# Matlab plots dynamic images

Tags: matlab

Is there a image type which u can save a matlab plot 'image' which is dynamic when resizing it?

I want to place it in a powerpoint slide and be able to resize it there with the plots axis also resizing with it.

Comment: In agreement with @kitchenette 's answer - what do you mean by dynamic? are you referring to [vector graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics)?

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely possible to save the MATLAB image as say, a pdf, and then resize the image proportionally in a powerpoint slide such that the axes grow proportionally to the stuff in the plot. But I don't think this is what you meant with your question. There's no way to say, change the axes labels dynamically once your image leaves MATLAB and is placed in a different application.